# Cannot get PUT request data in PHP

Tags: php

Im trying to retrieve the input field data from a HTTP PUT request.
Here is what I have tried with no success:

```
if($this->_method == 'PUT'){
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    parse_str($data, $this->_data);
}else $this->_data = $_POST;
```

But it returns empty string. I have tried both `multipart/form-data` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

What is the problem?

Comment: Are you possibly reading from php://input already? php://input does not support streaming, so if somewhere else in your code you have read from it, then you will need to store it somewhere. `multipart/form-data` is not supported with the input php wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, my mistake! I'm using `HttpRequest` class to send the requests, and put data wasn't added properly:

need `$request->addPutData($fields_string)` 
instead of `$request->addPostFields($fields_array);`

This way I can read `php://input` and $this->_data is properly set.